# Stop ssh service at specific port

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've started multiple ssh services at a range of port for a particular testing using

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -p portnumber
```

How do i stop service at a specific port where i've started ? 
I've seen this command (But dats general, i have to stop at a specific port)

```
/etc/init.d/ssh stop
```

Comment: What was off topic in this Question you moderators ??????                 Give me a proper answer if you can !!!!

Comment: @Kols It's not a programming question. Read the FAQ. Next time, post such questions on unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: @gertvdijk Aha. . . maybe they've lots of cleanup work to do with all the questions asked in the Long run. I've seen questions like this "without downvoted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop all instances you can use:

```
killall sshd
```

If you want a specific one you need to use `ps aux | grep sshd -p <port>`. There you get the pid (process id) which you can simply kill by `kill <pid>`.

Comment: No, i want to stop service to a specific port. Not all instances together.

Comment: Read the second part of my answer.

Comment: Thnx a bunch @rekire. 
eventhough kill is not a perfect way to end a process, i'll hv to stick with that for now. :)

Comment: @Kols init scripts also just send a `SIGTERM` signal to the process. Maybe you're confused with hard-killing processes using other signals such as the unsafe `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Kill is the normal way to close a daemon. Look into the start script. Just if you don't use the switch -9 the death will also be graseful.

Comment: rekire and @gertvdijk Thnx for de heads up :) . I'll accept this as an answer And i have No idea why are Moderators competing to down vote the question and closing it.

Comment: You could also try this here: `ps -fC sshd | grep "sshd <port>" | awk '{print $2}' | kill` but I have not test it.

Comment: @rekire yep i just had made a script for fetching  :)

Comment: `grep "sshd <port>" `: What if there are MULTIPLE spaces or additional options between "sshd" & "<port>"?

Comment: You could use a regular expression like `grep -e "sshd +<port>"`.

Comment: Here is what i did 
pid=`ps aux | grep "sshd -p $1" | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`
`kill $pid`